# Upgrading from 8.1 to 8.2 having an error

Tags: upgrade

this is the error that I get in log files.

`ERROR Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowHistory, Sitecore.Kernel (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).`

This is what I get in the browser:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowHistory,
>   Sitecore.Kernel (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not resolve type name:
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowHistory, Sitecore.Kernel (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Exception: Could not resolve type name:
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowHistory, Sitecore.Kernel (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).]
>   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method) +108
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +236
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +46
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +131
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   Boolean assert) +42
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   Boolean assert) +53
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode
>   processorNode) +66
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode
>   processorNode) +97
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters) +129
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +352
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
>   +162    Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +18
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args) +18    Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(String
>   pipelineName, PipelineArgs args) +49
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +156
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +472
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +534
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +352
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not resolve type name:
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowHistory, Sitecore.Kernel (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9947444 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +261
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

Comment: Better to check you sitecore.kernel.dll version with the fresh version.

Answer (score 8):

Pipeline `Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.ShowHistory` is no longer used.

Check your `web.config` (or `sitecore.config`) in `App_Config` and remove reference to this pipeline.

But, if you have issue with this pipeline, most probably you have more corrupted configs in your solution. You may want to compare them with the clean Sitecore 8.2 configs.